# How to find limit $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n^3}-\sqrt{n^3}}$

Tags: limits

Find limit:

$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n^3}-\sqrt{n^3}}$

I know that it is 4

Can someone tell me what is the way to solve this with steps or link to some recourse with explanation how to solve this.

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n^2+n^3}+\sqrt{n^3}$ and use $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

On the one hand, we have that

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n + 3} + \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}\times\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{n}} + 1\right)
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n^{2} + n^{3}} - \sqrt{n^{3}} = \sqrt{n}\times(\sqrt{n + n^{2}} - n)
\end{align*}

Hence the proposed limit is the same as
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n + 3} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^{2} + n^{3}} - \sqrt{n^{3}}} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{n}} + 1\right)\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{n + n^{2}} - n}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{n}} + 1\right)\times\frac{\sqrt{n + n^{2}} + n}{n}\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{1 + \frac{3}{n}} + 1\right)\times\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + 1} + 1\right)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?